# Refer to filename containing newline in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, escaping, dockerfile

I'm trying to use the `COPY` command with a directory name containing newlines and I tried to write it with `\n`, `\x0a` or with a literal newline, but docker doesn't find the directory with any of these approaches, though it does find it if I rename it to not have a newline character in it. The docker documentation also doesn't seem to mention this. How can I get this to work?

Minimal example:

```
$ touch $'foo\nbar'
$ echo -e 'FROM busybox\nCOPY "foo\\nbar" /tmp/\nCMD /bin/sh' >|Dockerfile
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.192kB
Step 1/3 : FROM busybox
 ---> 020584afccce
Step 2/3 : COPY "foo\nbar" /tmp/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder128029906/foo\nbar: no such file or directory
```

Comment: In case anyone tries this with BuildKit, I've opened the following issue: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1268

Comment: @BMitch Thanks, I've fixed the example. Glad to see my question leading to improvements!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
ADD ["\n.txt", "\n.txt"]
```

Looks like `\r`, `\b`, `\n` work, but `\x**` or `\e` do not. I have Docker version 19.03.5-ce, build 633a0ea838. I can't find any reference on this, so if someone finds it and sees this answer, feel free to edit it.

Comment: The json syntax works with both COPY and ADD, but will not work with BuildKit. I'll submit an issue on that.